# onMessageReceived no se ejecuta en segundo plano o cerrada

Tags: android

Hola estoy intentando recibir notificaciones que por ahora mando desde Firebase could Messaging, pero me he encontrado que cuando la app esta en segundo plano o cerrada, aunque llega las notificaciones no ejecuta onMessageReceived.

Cuando llega la notificacion en segundo plano se ve el titulo y el body de getNotification().getTitle()) y remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody()) en la notificacion y yo quiero que se vea remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo")) y remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle")) de las opciones adicionales.

Pero lo que me importa es que en segundo plano y cerrada no se ejecuta el metodo onMessageReceived .

```
Package com.valhondo.delgado.cofradiainfantil;

import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

import java.util.Random;

public class RecibirNotificaciones extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(@NonNull String token) {
        super.onNewToken( token );
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic( "enviaratodos" ).addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) { }
        } );
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(@NonNull RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived( remoteMessage );

        String from = remoteMessage.getFrom();

        Log.e("token", "Titulo : " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.e("token", "Detalle : " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        Log.e("token", "Canal : " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getChannelId());
        Log.e("token", "FROM : " + from);
        Log.e("token", "Titulo es : " + remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo"));
        Log.e("token", "Detalle es : " + remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle"));
        if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0 ) {
            String titulo  = remoteMessage.getData().get("titulo");
            String detalle  = remoteMessage.getData().get("detalle");
            mayorqueoreo (titulo, detalle);
        }
    }

    private void  mayorqueoreo(String titulo, String detalle) {
        String id = "mensaje";
        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService( Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE );
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder( RecibirNotificaciones.this, id );
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel( id, "nuevo", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH  );
            notificationChannel.setShowBadge(true);
            assert notificationManager != null;
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel( notificationChannel );
        }
        builder.setAutoCancel( true )
                .setWhen( System.currentTimeMillis() )
                .setContentTitle( titulo )
                .setSmallIcon( R.mipmap.ic_launcher )
                .setContentText( detalle )
                .setContentIntent( clicknoti() )
                .setContentInfo( "nuevo" );

        Random random = new Random(  );
        int idNotify = random.nextInt(8000);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.notify( idNotify, builder.build() );
    }

    public PendingIntent clicknoti() {
        Intent intent = new Intent( getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class );
        intent.putExtra( "color", "rojo" );
        intent.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        return PendingIntent.getActivity( RecibirNotificaciones.this, 0, intent, 0 );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo tengo solucionaado.
La cuestion esta en que desde Firebase no funciona bien pero desde otra App en el mismo proyecto el envio de Notificaciones PUSH si.

Este es el codigo para mandar Notificaciones PUSH que completa en del mensaje anterior en la APP que recibe el mensaje.

```
                RequestQueue myrequest = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

            try {
                // enviaratodos es la subcripcion que se realiza en la APP receptora, se puede poner cualquier nombre pero en todos los lados el mismo
                json.put( "to", "/topics/enviaratodos");
                JSONObject notificacion = new JSONObject();
                notificacion.put( "titulo", "Titulo de la Notificacion");
                notificacion.put( "detalle", "Detalle de la Notificacion");
                json.put( "data", notificacion );

                String URL = "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send";

                JsonObjectRequest request = new  JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST,URL,json,null, null ) {

                    @Override
                    public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {

                        Map<String, String> header = new HashMap<>();
                        header.put("Content-type", "application/json");
                        header.put("authorization", "key=Llave que esta en Firebase en la parte de could Menssaging");
                        return header;
                    }
                };

                myrequest.add(request);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```